# Using a variable inside Array() in PHP

Tags: php

I wanting to sort the contents of a array, depending on the dynamic data that is loaded in to the page.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $x; $i++) {
    if ($string != "") $string = $string . ", ";
    $string = $string . "\"$id[$i]\" => \"$land[$i]\"";

}
echo $string . "<br>"; //1
$my_array = array($string);
print_r($my_array); //2

asort($my_array);
print_r($my_array); //3


$my_array = array("832838" => "32", "233463" => "3");

asort($my_array);
print_r($my_array); //4
```

Produces this output

```
1 "832838" => "32", "233463" => "3"
2 Array ( [0] => "832838" => "32", "233463" => "3" ) 
3 Array ( [0] => "832838" => "32", "233463" => "3" ) 
4 Array ( [233463] => 3 [832838] => 32 )
```

Line 1 is what is output from the for statement for Line 3 it is put through asort using the variable, and Line 4 direct input, checking where the error was, when putting through the array() function using a variable is where the mess up happens, is there a way around this?

Comment: Try `usort($my_array, 'custom_function')`. You will need to create `function custom_function($a, $b)`, where you compare them however you want.

Comment: That look something that would be very complex, when the problem is with array() and not the sorting

Comment: in the for loop at the beginning, why not create the array right there instead? that will surely save you alot of trouble

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create array from string like yours. Use this:

```
$string = '"832838" => "32", "233463" => "3"';
$my_array = eval("return array({$string});");
```

Comment: this is an evil thing in terms of security

Answer (score 0):

Use rsort function to solve .

```
<?php
$fruits = array("lemon", "orange", "banana", "apple");
rsort($fruits);
foreach ($fruits as $key => $val) {
    echo "$key = $val\n";
}
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
0 = orange
1 = lemon
2 = banana
3 = apple
```

Comment: The sorting isn't the problem at all its the creating of the array which is the problem